# How to get unique device numer in Android?

Tags: android

I have tried to these methods such as IMEI,MEID,mac address,android_id, but all not OK.

How to get unique device numer in Android?

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id) SO question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

Comment: Did you search this before posting ?

Answer (score 4):

There are several Unique Identifiers available for Android devices

**IMEI**

```
TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String imei = TelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
```

permission

```
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
```

**WLAN MAC Address**

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
String wanMAC = wifi .getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
```

permission

```
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
```

**Bluetooth MAC Address**

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter =BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
String bluetoothMAC = bluetoothAdapter .getAddress();
```

permission

```
android.permission.BLUETOOTH
```

**Android ID**

```
String androidID = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: Please note:  not all devices will have an IMEI, not all cell technologies use it, and devices without a cell connection won't.  You can only get the MAC address if the appropriate hardware is on, and as of Android 6.0 the APIs will return a garbage value

Comment: IMEI and Android ID Will not working in Android 10, as it is restricted

Comment: MAC address can not be found with Android Version 11. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66257004/how-to-get-mac-address-from-an-android-device-with-os-11

Comment: Yes, As per the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#java added restrictions for android hardware identifiers

Answer (score 2):

As the requirement for most of the applications is to identify a particular installation and not a physical device, a good solution to get the unique id for a user if to use UUID class. The following solution has been presented by Reto Meier from Google in a Google I/O presentation :

```
private static String uniqueID = null;
private static final String PREF_UNIQUE_ID = "PREF_UNIQUE_ID";
public synchronized static String id(Context context) {
   if (uniqueID == null) {
      SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
         PREF_UNIQUE_ID, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      uniqueID = sharedPrefs.getString(PREF_UNIQUE_ID, null);
      if (uniqueID == null) {
         uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
         Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
     editor.putString(PREF_UNIQUE_ID, uniqueID);
     editor.commit();
     }
   }
   return uniqueID;
}
```

UUID.randomUUID() method generates an unique identifier for a specific installation. You have just to store that value and your user will be identified at the next launch of your application. You can also try to associate this solution with Android Backup service to keep the information available to the user even if he installs your application on the other device.

You can explore more at https://medium.com/@ssaurel/how-to-retrieve-an-unique-id-to-identify-android-devices-6f99fd5369eb

Answer (score 2):

In Android 10 you can't have access to non resettable device ids, like IMEI ,MEID etc.

So I think your best chance is creating a UUID. You can do that using the code below and saving this UUID into database or preference file.

```
   String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

As a random number, everytime you call this method it'll return a different code, and I think is not you are looking for.

To get a "unique ID" from UUID, the best choise  is the code below.It will work fine, but the documentation ask to avoid using Android_ID too.

```
   String androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

   UUID androidId_UUID = UUID
            .nameUUIDFromBytes(androidId.getBytes("utf8"));
```

This code will give you a almost unique code because if the user do a factory reset, this number would be changed.

I'm looking for another way to get a unique ID but, until now, I couldn't find.

Here ar some Android Developers documentation that should be usefull.
Good pratices to define a unique ID
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

How to define a unique Id based in you use case:

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#common-use-cases

I hope this could help someone.

Answer (score 1):

**Below code is I used in my project**

To get Unique **Android Id**

```
 static String androidID = Settings.Secure.getString(MyApplication.getContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

I used this as a global so i can use anywhere in my project

Answer (score 0):

**To retrieve the unique ID associated to your device, you can use the following code :**

```
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.content.Context;
// ...
 TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
  telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.
                TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        /*
      * getDeviceId() returns the unique device ID.
       * For example,the IMEI for GSM and the MEID or ESN for CDMA phones.
         */
            String deviceId = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
         /*
       * getSubscriberId() returns the unique subscriber ID,
         * For example, the IMSI for a GSM phone.
          */
           String subscriberId = telephonyManager.getSubscriberId();
```

**Secure Android ID**

```
String androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                 Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: IMEI and Android ID Will not working in Android 10, as it is restricted