# How can I get the MAC address from an Android device with Android 11?

Tags: android, operating-system, mac-address, android-11

We are using `NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress()` to get the MAC address, but as we can see from *[MAC address availability changes in Android 11](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#mac-11-plus)*, now it will not be used for [Android 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_11).

Is there a solution to this or any guideline?

Comment: You cannot get the mac address of the device on android 11, a workaround is to set your targetSdk level to 29.

Answer (score 3):

Android guidelines enforces to stop using MAC addresses as identification. As the link you posted, there are other alternatives. If you want to use a MAC addresses in Android 11 is almost impossible to get the same MAC address, even with [hafiza's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66257004/how-can-i-get-the-mac-address-from-an-android-device-with-android-11/66310610#66310610) (you forgot to tell that there are some additional manifest permissions).

In my app, I used MAC address verification until [Android 9.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Pie) (Pie), but now I'm using the library *[FingerprintJS Android](https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprint-android)* which is a really helpful solution to get some kind of id. I've tested on Android 9.0, [Android 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_10) and Android 11 without any real problems or randomized values.

Comment: does this provides MAC address for OS 11 ?

Answer (score 1):

In my Android project I was using the following code to get the MAC address working on all versions of Android.

But now it is ***no more***... so now we cannot get the MAC address. See *[Don't work with MAC addresses](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#mac-addresses)*.

The old way that we were using to get the MAC address:

```
public static String getMacAddress() {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface networkInterface : all) {
            if (!networkInterface.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0"))
                continue;

            byte[] macBytes = networkInterface.getHardwareAddress();
            if (macBytes == null) {
                return "";
            }

            StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
            Log.e("Get MAC address", "getMacAddr: " + res1.toString());
            for (byte b : macBytes) {
                // res1.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF) + ":");
                res1.append(String.format("%02X:", b));
            }

            if (res1.length() > 0) {
                res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
            }
            return res1.toString().replace(":", "-");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("TAG", "getMacAddr: ", ex);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this code with Android 11 ? is it giving values ?

Comment: NO, i have just taken your code and tested in device but it is not working

Comment: @hafiza if you set your targetSdk to 30 your code won't work.

Comment: **This will not work for Android 11 (Above sdk 30 )**  for more read here https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#mac-addresses

Comment: @Prasath you are right.

Comment: Any alternative solution for Android 11

Comment: @Rohit My `targetSdkVersion` is 18 and it still doesn't work on the new device.

Answer (score 0):

With this code, I am able to get the MAC address in Android 11.

```
fun getEthMac(): String {
    var macAddress = "Not able to read the MAC address"
    var br: BufferedReader? = null
    try {
        br = BufferedReader(FileReader("/sys/class/net/eth0/address"))
        macAddress = br.readLine().uppercase()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
    return macAddress
}
```

It is important to note that this file location might be different for different devices and different Android versions. So it's important to test this function on different devices and different Android versions to make sure that the file is accessible and the MAC address can be read correctly.

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/net/wlan0/address: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)` :(