# .NET MAUI device MAC address

Tags: c#, maui

I am trying to get the MAC address of the current device in .NET MAUI. This is on Android/Windows and iOS.

It looks like NetworkInterfaces is not working as it was.

Consider this code:

```csharp
public string get_mac()
{
    int c = 0;

    try
    {
        NetworkInterface[] ni = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        for (c = 0; c < ni.Length; c++)
        {
            if (ni[c].NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
            {
                PhysicalAddress pa = ni[c].GetPhysicalAddress();
                return pa.ToString();
            }
        }
        return "!Ethernet Not Found!";
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Globals.log.add(ex);
        return "!" + ex.Message;
    }
}
```

It looks like all of the interfaces are set to a type of "Unknown" and the physical address (MAC) of each is set to `""`. It looks like it is properly getting the network name.

Is NetworkInterface even valid in .NET MAUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is no.

For iOS, the iOS sandbox prevents an app from getting the device's MAC address. You could refer to *[MAC Address of the iPhone](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/112003)* and *[File system access in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system)*.

For Android, now we cannot. You could refer to this issue: *[How can I get the MAC address from an Android device with OS 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66310610/20118901)* and the official documentation *[Don't work with MAC addresses](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#mac-addresses)*.

Comment: It looks like the direction for most operating systems is to keep the mac private. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

For the Windows platform, this code works properly;

```csharp
string macAddress = (from nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
                         where nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
                         select nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()
                    ).FirstOrDefault();
```

It's a bit problematic for Android and iOS, as [Liqun Shen-MSFT said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76060302/11587992).